# what the issue with my update function ? that updated perfectly after sqlite databse locked error?

Tags: ios, sqlite, thread-safety

```
- (void) updateTimeStamp:(NSDictionary *) record forRowID: (NSString *) updateTableName
  {
    int dictionarySize = [record count];

NSMutableData *dKeys = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:sizeof(id) *dictionarySize];

NSMutableData * dValues = [NSMutableData dataWithLength: sizeof(id) * dictionarySize];
[record getObjects:(__unsafe_unretained id *)dValues.mutableBytes andKeys:(__unsafe_unretained id *)dKeys.mutableBytes];

[dValues appendBytes:&updateTableName length:sizeof(id)];

NSString * query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update %@ set %@ = ? where  Table_Name= ?",tableName,[[record allKeys] componentsJoinedByString:@" = ?, "]];
[self bindSQL:[query UTF8String] withVargs:(va_list)dValues.mutableBytes];


if(sqlite3_step(statment) == SQLITE_DONE);
{
     NSLog(@"prepead Timestamp %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
sqlite3_reset(statment);
@synchronized(self)
{

    if(sqlite3_finalize(statment) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"doQuery: sqlite3_finalize failed (%s)", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    }

}

 }
```

When i run application that function work perfectly? not an any issue but that function after database is locked ? what the problem with the function please give me solution

i have many table so i open database once time in function  when all timestamp updated after close the database.

bindSQL function below

```
  - (void) bindSQL:(const char *) cQuery withVargs:(va_list)vargs
  {
    int param_count;

NSLog(@"%d",sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, cQuery, -1, &statment, NULL));
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, cQuery, -1, &statment, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"bindSQL: could not prepare statement (%s) %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database), cQuery);
    statment = NULL;
    return;
}

if((param_count = sqlite3_bind_parameter_count(statment)))
{
    for(int i =0; i < param_count ;i++)
    {
        id object = va_arg(vargs,id);

        if(object == nil)
        {
            sqlite3_bind_null(statment, i+1);
        }
        else if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(objCType)])
        {
            if(strchr("islqISLBQ", *[object objCType]))
            {
                sqlite3_bind_int(statment, i+1, [object intValue]);
            }
            else if (strchr("fd", *[object objCType]))
            {
                sqlite3_bind_double(statment, i+1, [object doubleValue]);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"bindSQL: Unhandled objCType: %s query: %s", [object objCType], cQuery);
                statment = NULL;
                return;
            }
        }
        else if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(UTF8String)])
        {
            sqlite3_bind_text(statment, i+1, [object UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }
        else if ([object isEqual:[NSNull null]])
        {
            statment = NULL;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"bindSQL: Unhandled parameter type: %@ query: %s", [object class], cQuery);
            statment = NULL;
            return;
        }
    }
}

va_end(vargs);
return;
 }
```

Comment: WTF is going on with that code?

Comment: this code work perfectly and what u not understand in this code @trojanfoe

Comment: It is bonkers though.

Comment: Show the `bindSQL` code.

Comment: i am adding bindSQL function @CL.

Answer (score 0):

This code creates two statement objects:

```
NSLog(@"%d",sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, cQuery, -1, &statment, NULL));
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, cQuery, -1, &statment, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
```

of which only one is finalized later.

If you want to check the return code, better use a variable:

```
int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, cQuery, -1, &statment, NULL);
NSLog(@"%d", rc);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
```

Comment: same database lock error occurred. i open close database perfectly i check many times. what the issue i didn't get in my code. @CL.